# Invoke a directive's method via watching API object, how do you identify the directive instance?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I want to provide the directive API, so that the directives can communicate each other. I am using an API object and $watch to implement it. The below is my example

http://plnkr.co/edit/n1dVBzRkaJucFjZD48ny?p=preview

```
function GreetingController($scope, greetingApi) {
    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.api = greetingApi;

    $scope.$watch('api.username', updateUsername);

    function updateUsername () {
        ctrl.username = greetingApi.username;
    }

}
```

The directive "greeting" watch the service "greetingApi". If "greetingApi.username" is changed, the greeting directive's updateUsername() method will be called.

The problem is that if there are multiple greeting directives in a page, the updagteUsername() method of all of directives will be triggered?

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. Is API object a good pattern to provide directive API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in assigning a service object as scope property, the controllers become thinner and easier to test.

But this

```
function updateUsername () {
    ctrl.username = greetingApi.username;
}
```

works against this concept.

`greetingApi` should work as a model and single source of truth, it has already been exposed to the scope and is available for binding as `{{ api.username }}`.